# Without an applicationvisibility entry, how does Salesforce determine the default application?

Tags: deployment, profile

If I create a new profile by deploying an XML file using Ant, and I neglect to include a default application in the profile's ApplicationVisibility nodes, how does SalesForce determine which existing application is default, and can I control this though any deployable files or database scripts?

I have done this once, and it *appears* as if Salesforce simply chose the oldest application, but I'd love to know where this behavior is documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to be clarified before I potentially answer your question: Profiles are never created. They are cloned (just like you do with the UI). So, which profile you ask? The Standard profile associated with the User License associated with your "new" profile is cloned and then overridden with all the new permissions that you are sending over (there is a userLicense tag in Profile XML - check it out). Salesforce license gets "Standard User" (API Name = Standard), Platform license gets "Platform Standard User" (API Name = StandardAul) etc.

Now, to your question: So, what are the defaults for a truncated "new" profile? It is whatever you have designated in your Standard* profile.

Hope this answers. Please feel free to reach out in case you need more info (sridhar at dreamfactory dot com).

Sridhar

Comment: Thanks for the excellent clarification on this process, I didn't make the connection between being forced to clone these when creating new and the profiles created when I deploy, it's very obvious in hindsight.

I hadn't thought that the standard user would be modified with this app default, but there it is. Exactly what I needed. 

I actually 'discovered' the userLicense tag yesterday right after making this post, when a profile was moved to a common repository to capture permissions on common objects and it was left out, leading to a license mismatch after the deploy.